# Нужна ли запятая в предложении? И поясните, пожалуйста

Tags: пунктуация

"А потом у каждого возраста свои особенности."

Comment: А какое предложение стоит перед этим? Приведите его, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

*Потом* может быть наречием-обстоятельством и вводным словом.

Примеры [Д.Э.Розенталь. Вводные слова и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122):

***И потом он стал знаменитым*** — "затем; после этого".

***И, потом, он в моих глазах знаменитость.***

В вашем примере *потом* - это вводное слово, поэтому требуется его  обособление. После А запятую обычно не ставят.

*А потом, у каждого возраста свои особенности.*

Как  вводное слово *потом* чаще употребляется в разговорном стиле.

Answer (score 1):

**А потом, у каждого возраста свои особенности.**

1) Это вводное слово (оно обособляется).  **Почему именно вводное слово, а не наречие?** (Ответ на этот вопрос — это и есть **решение данной задачи**).

2) Дело в том, что **значение наречия** (без обособления) здесь **не подходит:** у каждого возраста свои особенности и сначала, и потом, а не только потом.

3) **Союз А примыкает** к вводному слову и не отделяется запятой.

4) Вводное выражение имеет значение **"а кроме того"** и используется **для оформления речи** при построении рассуждения.

Comment: *>> Значение наречия (без обособления) не подходит*. Ну да, не подходит... Маленькие все одинаковые, а потом у каждого возраста свои особенности.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

***А потом у каждого возраста свои особенности.***

Здесь "потом" — союз.